# Twitter bootstrap icons don't show up - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, icons

i'm a newbie, so please help ;-)

I build a small RoR web application where i'm trying to use the twitter bootstrap.js framework.

i got almost everything to work but showing the icons which should be coming glyphicons-halflings-white.png or glyphicons-halflings.png .

my folders structure is pretty simple, the standard RoR project, where i put the png files under /app/assets/images/, and when i take a look on the bootstrap.css files i see:

```
background-image: url("../images/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
```

and

```
background-image: url("../images/glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

which should be correct according to my folder structure.

In my html code i have something like that:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" id="addTagButton"><i class="icon-tag"></i>Add Tag</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

where i use the `<i class="icon-tag"></i>` to show a tag icon (or hope to see it)

**Though, nothing is working**

for unknown reason, i can't see any icons on my folder. i was trying to see if i can see the png files if i simple copy the `../images/glyphicons-halflings.png` to the browser address url, though, i get "No route matches [GET] "/images/glyphicons-halflings.png" when the url points to: localhost:3000/images/glyphicons-halflings.png

my html response looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-responsive.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/chosen.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery-ui.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.1.8.20.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.extentions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/select2.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/assets/select2.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="c+czIHCNmepmx674gKldijipFRD9348Gw+R2SAlrpow=" name="csrf-token" />
  <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<script src="/assets/jquery.validate.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jit-yc.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/graphcontrol.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/excanvas.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/assets/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

<h1>Sandbox#hello</h1>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" id="addTagButton"><i class="icon-tag"></i>Add Tag</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>



<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am i doing anything wrong? do i need to force ruby to deploy those *.png files correctly?

Any advise would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem so i did this:

```
<i class="icon-shopping-cart glyphw" id="cart"></i>
```

css

```
.glyphw{
    background-image: url(/assets/glyphicons-halflings-white.png);
}
```

Comment: why does this work even though images are under assets/images and not directly under /assets/ in the project? does rails actually move everything in the subfolders up to /assets/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the closely-maintained **bootstrap-sass** gem (https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) to save all headaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
    url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

just set your font directory correctly in font-awesome.css

Answer (score 0):

Solution I use for these kind of issues (where vendor scripts try to find assets in `/img`, 
`/images` is to redirect those request to `assets` folder. In `routes.rb` add:

```
  get '/img/:name', to: redirect {|params, req| "/assets/#{params[:name]}.#{params[:format]}" }
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Twitter bootstrap to my projects and it's awesome. The syntax to get an icon is:

```
<i class="icon icon-tag"></i>
```

The first CSS class "`icon`" is to make a tag like an icon and the second class "`icon-tag`" is to show the icon image.